# How to repair mesh without leaving holes in the mesh

Tags: mesh, transforms

Noob in SE and blender. Using Blender 3.2.1, win 10.

In the character shown below, I would like to remove the sword tip and arm pit webs without creating a hole in the mesh.  I have tried delete, crease, et.al. with no success.

[image]

full body image

[image]

sword tip

[image]

arm pit webs

Comment: Have you tried with the Lasso Trim in Sculpt mode (keep pressing on the Box Trim to have access to it)

Comment: Thanks for the response, moonboots.
The lasso does allow finer selections, but...
After making the selection with the lasso and tapping the delete key, I still get holes in the mesh.

I have tried every selection in the delete pop-up, and still get holes :-(

Comment: I'm not talking about the selection lasso, I'm talking about the Lasso Trim in Sculpt mode, have you tried (not sure it will work though) https://zupimages.net/up/22/29/jd1r.jpg

Comment: Voila!  That works!
It is relatively slow, but now I have something that I can work with.
Merci

Answer (score 0):

Try to cut your object with the *Lasso Trim* in *Sculpt* mode (keep pressing on the Box Trim to have access to it:

[image]